# Python pandas conditional logic/using where while merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, conditional-statements

I have these DFs

**df1**

```
user_id     code     name     code_equivalence             name_equivalence
51          123    bi lovers            542                bi for marketing
51          123    bi lovers            545                i love bi
51          234    datascience          345                data and science
51          234    datascience          555                data lovers
51          255    antiquity history    429                roma
51          255    antiquity history    430                greece
52          123    bi lovers            542                bi for marketing
52          123    bi lovers            545                i love bi
52          256    modern history       500                france
52          256    modern history       501                germany
52          200    arts                 400                arts I
52          200    arts                 401                arts II
```

**df2**

```
user_id     code     name       status
51          123    bi lovers    ongoing
51          430    greece       ongoing
52          501    germany      ongoing
52          050    numbers      ongoing
```

I want to merge them by checking if df2 code is either the same as df1 code or df1 code_equivalence and df2 name is either the same as df1 name or df1 name_equivalence to get df2 status.
Like this:

**merge df**

```
user_id     code     name               code_equivalence    name_equivalence        status
51          123    bi lovers            542                 bi for marketing        ongoing
51          123    bi lovers            545                 i love bi               ongoing
51          234    datascience          345                 data and science        (null)
51          234    datascience          555                 data lovers             (null)
51          255    antiquity history    429                 roma                    (null)
51          255    antiquity history    430                 greece                  ongoing
52          123    bi lovers            542                 bi for marketing        (null)
52          123    bi lovers            545                 i love bi               (null)
52          256    modern history       500                 france                  (null)
52          256    modern history       501                 germany                 ongoing
52          200    arts                 400                 arts I                  (null)
52          200    arts                 401                 arts II                 (null)
```

After that, I want to transform data to make a new df, looking like this:

**final df**

```
user_id     code     name               code_equivalence    name_equivalence                    status
51          123    bi lovers            [542, 545]          [bi for marketing, i love bi]       ongoing
51          234    datascience          [345, 555]          [data and science, data lovers]     (null)
51          255    antiquity history    [429, 430]          [roma, greece]                      ongoing
52          123    bi lovers            [542, 545]          [bi for marketing, i love bi]       (null)
52          256    modern history       [500, 501]          [france, germany]                   ongoing
52          200    arts                 [400, 401]          [arts I, arts II]                   (null)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: solid requirements, but what issues have you come across so far? `merge` and `groupby` are the right tools you'll need for this task.

Comment: even using left join, i lose df1 unique code and name when using merge

Comment: Can you check the 5th row of your merge_df? Based on df1 and df2 I don't think there should be a match, so shouldn't it be (null) in the status column? I mean the row with code = 255, and name_eq = roma.

Comment: @Michał89 yea, you are right. It's null

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got the ask correctly, but from what I read you did the merging and now you're looking to get the `final result`?  If so, that should do the job, considering `merged` is your merged data frame.

```
 >>> merged.groupby(['user_id','code','name']).agg(list).reset_index()
   user_id  code               name code_equivalence                 name_equivalence              status
0       51   123          bi lovers       [542, 545]    [bi for marketing, i love bi]  [ongoing, ongoing]
1       51   234        datascience       [345, 555]  [data and science, data lovers]    [(null), (null)]
2       51   255  antiquity history       [429, 430]                   [roma, greece]   [(null), ongoing]
3       52   123          bi lovers       [542, 545]    [bi for marketing, i love bi]    [(null), (null)]
4       52   200               arts       [400, 401]                [arts I, arts II]       [(null), nan]
5       52   256     modern history       [500, 501]                [france, germany]   [(null), ongoing]
```

Here is the complete solution anyway, if you just have `df1` & `df2`:

```
 >>> (pd
     ...: .merge(df1,df2, left_on=['user_id','code','name'], right_on=['user_id','code','name'], how='left')
     ...: .groupby(['user_id','code','name'])
     ...: .agg(list)
     ...: .reset_index())

   user_id  code               name code_equivalence                 name_equivalence              status
0       51   123          bi lovers       [542, 545]    [bi for marketing, i love bi]  [ongoing, ongoing]
1       51   234        datascience       [345, 555]  [data and science, data lovers]          [nan, nan]
2       51   255  antiquity history       [429, 430]                   [roma, greece]          [nan, nan]
3       52   123          bi lovers       [542, 545]    [bi for marketing, i love bi]          [nan, nan]
4       52   200               arts       [400, 401]                [arts I, arts II]          [nan, nan]
5       52   256     modern history       [500, 501]                [france, germany]          [nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is how I get to the **merge_df** DataFrame in three steps:

1. merging on first condition
2. merging on second condition
3. filling missing matchings from step 1 with matchings from step 2.

   ```
   merge_df = pd.merge(df1, df2[["code","status"]], left_on=["code"], right_on=["code",], how="left")
   merge_df2 = pd.merge(df1, df2[["code","status"]], left_on=["code_equivalence"], right_on=["code",], how="left")
   merge_df["status"].fillna(merge_df2["status"], inplace=True)
   ```

However I would like to know if there's a one-liner to do that (probably yes).